# React | Add className to a dynamically created component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I am trying to add a className property to a newly created component like this:

```js
const component = <Icons.RightArrowIcon /> // I want to add a className to this component

// Then...

// ...

return (
    <>{component}</>
)
```

I wrote the following code:

```js
type IconButtonProps = {
  icon: 'RightArrowIcon' | 'WordIcon';
  className?: string;
};
// eslint-disable-next-line react/display-name
const IconButton = React.forwardRef<any, IconButtonProps>((props, ref) => {
  const getIcon = () => {
    let icon: React.ReactNode | null = null

    if (props.icon === 'RightArrowIcon') {
      icon = <Icons.RightArrowIcon />
    } else if (props.icon === 'WordIcon') {
      icon = <Icons.WordIcon />
    }

    // This is what I thought it would be
    if (icon !== null) { icon.props.className = styles.icon_button__icon }

    return icon
  }

  return (
    <div
      ref={ref}
      className={`${props.className} ${styles.icon_button__wrapper}`}
    >
      <button className={styles.icon_button}>
        {getIcon()}
      </button>
    </div>
  )
})

export default IconButton
```

But I got this error:

> TypeError: Cannot add property className, object is not extensible

Comment: Just for reference：  https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-playground-forked-3f9stb

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it needs to be that complicated. Why not just render the icon conditionally?

```
  return (
    <div
      ref={ref}
      className={`${props.className} ${styles.icon_button__wrapper}`}
    >
      <button className={styles.icon_button}>
        {
         props.icon === 'RightArrowIcon'?//or any condition here
         (
         <Icons.RightArrowIcon className={style.anyClassHere}/>
         ):
        (
         <Icons.WordIcon className={style.anyClassHere}/>
        )
        }
      </button>
      
    </div>
  )
```

Comment: I would like to start avoiding logic inside the markup, if there is no other way to do it like I would like it to, I would be doing this, Thank you